# rotate CIImage around center with CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cifilter, ciimage

I'm trying to rotate the pixel data of a CMSampleBuffer (coming from the camera) and display it in a UIImageView. I Don't want to rotate the view itself. It has to be the actual pixel data.

I grab the feed, convert it to a CIImage and with a CIFilter I rotate it.
I'm having trouble with setting the point around which it has to rotate. 
Right now it rotates around the lower left point. I want to rotate it around its center.

```
 func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

            //create pixelbuffer

            let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
            let context = CIContext.init(options: nil)

            // calculating the radians to rotate the ciimage by
            let radians : Float = atan2f(Float(boxView!.transform.b), Float(boxView!.transform.a));
            //create ciimage from the pixelbuffer

            let options = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey as String: true,
                kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey as String: true,]
            let ci = CIImage.init(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: options)
            //transform filter
            let filter = CIFilter.init(name: "CIAffineTransform")
            //set translation point to center
            var transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY)
            //rotate
            transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat(radians))
            // set translation point back again to normal
            var transformBack = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.view.frame.midX, y: -self.view.frame.midY)
            //applying the transform
            transform.concatenating(transformBack)

            filter!.setValue(transform, forKey: kCIInputTransformKey)
            filter!.setValue(ci, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let output = filter?.outputImage
            let img = context.createCGImage(output!, from: imageView!.frame)
            // send image to be displayed
            self.imageView!.image = UIImage(cgImage: img!)

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

found it. I have to apply transformations to the transformation variable itself.

```
let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.frame.midX, y: self.view.frame.midY).rotate(angle: CGFloat(radians)).translatedBy(x: -self.view.frame.midX, y: -self.view.frame.midY)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was loosing my mind around trigonometry before searching for a simpler solution. Translating, rotating, and translating back is more than enough. Maybe with math it might be more performant, but for now this will do the trick. :) Thank you again!!

Comment: I think the answer was about CIImage, not UIView, this might confuse the readers.

Comment: what do you mean? my question was about CIImage, I explicitly state I want to rotate a CIImage instead of the UIView, so my answer was correct.

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 5:**

```
let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: yourBuffer)
let rotatedImage = image.oriented(.right)
```

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/2919727-oriented)

Comment: Quite simple. Thanks! Just what I needed.

Comment: Couldn't be any easier.  It took me over an hour to find this simple answer.  Thank you!